# Play YouTube Videos in WPF

Tags: wpf, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to find an example of playing youtube videos in my wpf app. Every example I find is outdated and not working.
I've tried to play the videos through the wpf webbrowser but that doesn't seem to work.
Does anybody has any sample code or links on how to play youtube videos in wpf by simply providing a URL which links to the correct video.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF

Comment: This is one of the links I've found but it's outdated and doesn't work anymore. The API has changed completely

Comment: It should work with webbrowser, did you tried cefsharp? It uses chrome internally instead of IE, may be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking to the embedded player seems to work. Just grab the video id from the original link and paste it into the embedded link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**YE7VzlLtp-4**

https://www.youtube.com/embed/**YE7VzlLtp-4**

A better solution would imo be to use a WebKit/Gecko based browser control, because this will give you much better HTML5 support. Something like GeckoFx or CefSharp should do the job.